# If $x$ is an element of the finite group $G$ and $|x| = |G|$, prove that $G = \langle x \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $x$ is an element of the finite group $G$ and $|x| = |G|$, prove that $G = \langle x \rangle$. Give an explicit example to show that this result need not be true if $G$ is an infinite group.

I am wondering if I can get some hint for this question? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** any group containing $x$ also contains $\langle x \rangle$.

**Counterexamples:**

- $|\mathbb Z|=|\langle 1 \rangle|=|\langle 2 \rangle|=|2\mathbb Z|$
- $|0 \times \mathbb Z|=
  |\langle (0,1) \rangle|=
  |\langle (0,1),(1,0) \rangle|=
  |\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}|$

Comment: Dear Omnomnomnom - thanks. I got that any group containing $x$ also contains $⟨x⟩$. Can I just argue because $x \in G$ so $⟨x⟩ \in G$. And since they have the same cardinality, they are equal?

Comment: You mean $\langle x \rangle\subseteq G$. But yes.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Out of curiosity, how would you show that $G \subseteq \langle x \rangle$? Would you need Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: @Adriano cardinality is enough here. For any finite set $T$: if $S\subseteq T$ and $|S|=|T|$, then $S=T$.

Answer (score 3):

$$|2|=|\mathbb Z|=\infty $$
 But $$2\mathbb Z\varsubsetneq\mathbb Z
$$